# c++ constructor not working

Tags: c++, class, constructor

This is my makeAccount.cpp:

```
#include "account.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int makeAccount::getAccountNumber()
{
    return accountNumber;
}

double makeAccount::getAccountSaldo()
{
    return accountSaldo;
}

string makeAccount::getName()
{
    return name;
}

makeAccount::makeAccount(std::string naam, int id, double saldo)
{
    naam = name;
    id = accountNumber;
    saldo = accountSaldo;
}
```

this is my makeAccount.h

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class makeAccount
{
public:
    makeAccount(std::string naam, int id, double saldo);
    int getAccountNumber();
    double getAccountSaldo();
    std::string getName();
private:
    int accountNumber;
    double accountSaldo;
    std::string name;
};
```

this is my main.cpp

```
#include "account.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    makeAccount::makeAccount test("test", 30,  23.5);
    cout << test.getName() << endl;
    cout << test.getAccountNumber() << endl;
    cout << test.getAccountSaldo() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now I have the following problem, when I try to execute this code I get this:
1606416736
6.95322e-310
I think there is a problem in my account.h where I declare the constructor but I can't figure out what exactly is the problem. However when I do something like this:

```
private:
    int accountNumber = 1234;
    double accountSaldo = 1;
    std::string name = "test";
};
```

It does work, so I think i either way have something wrong in my constructor or where in my makeAccount.cpp where I have this code:

```
makeAccount::makeAccount(std::string naam, int id, double saldo)
{
    naam = name;
    id = accountNumber;
    saldo = accountSaldo;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to what the others said in their answers, the member functions you show here should all be `const`, as they don't modify anything. And strings should usually be passed as `std::string const&`, at least in pre-C++11. Finally, `makeAccount` is a strange class name. C++ does not have official naming conventions, but I've never seen anyone write class names like this. The most common conventions would be "MakeAccount" or "make_account".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have your assignments reversed.

You'll want this:

```
makeAccount::makeAccount(std::string naam, int id, double saldo)
{
    name = naam;
    accountNumber = id;
    accountSaldo = saldo;
}
```

Normally you'd want to use an initialization list, your constructor should look like this:

```
makeAccount::makeAccount(std::string naam, int id, double saldo) :
  accountNumber(id),
  accountSaldo(saldo),
  name(naam)
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
makeAccount::makeAccount(std::string naam, int id, double saldo)
{ 
naam = name;
id = accountNumber;
saldo = accountSaldo;
}
```

with:

```
makeAccount::makeAccount(std::string naam, int id, double saldo)
{
name = naam;
accountNumber = id;
accountSaldo = saldo;
}
```

now should works